# Paragraph meaning

Tags: paraphrasing

> But debate on the degree to which Beowulf; for example, has been
> modified by a relatively sophisticated Latin culture—not only by
> Christian sentiment but, as has been claimed, by a Virgilian
> tradition—cannot be resolved without knowledge of more details than
> **it seems likely we shall ever possess about primitive Anglo-Saxon beliefs**.
>
> — [*A Critial History of English Literature*, p7](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Vw3pHYZuF68C&pg=PA7) (David Daiches)

I can't understand the meaning after 'than'. Is 'than' used for comparison here?

If he had written like '... cannot be resolved without knowledge of more details than we shall ever possess about primitive Anglo-Saxon beliefs', it would have clearly shown a comparison. But using 'it seems likely' confuses me and make me think that the author has a different thought here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have understood it correctly. Instead of saying *We shall never know enough about Anglo-Saxon beliefs to resolve this question*, the author is being more cautious by saying that it *seems unlikely* that we shall ever have this knowledge.

Comment: But he wrote 'likely'

Comment: Yes - the question 'cannot be resolved without [more] knowledge... than it seems likely we shall ever possess'. That is, it is unlikely that we shall ever have enough knowledge to resolve it.

Comment: @RADS You could think of "it seems likely" as an aside. You could put it in parentheses without changing the meaning (though there's no need to): "... without knowledge of more details than (it seems likely) we shall ever possess...."

Comment: @Andy Bonner 'Than' is comparing which two things here?

Comment: The knowledge we currently have about Anglo-Saxon beliefs, and the knowledge we would need to have to answer that question about _Beowulf_.